# Failed to initiate ap scan : how avoid it?

Tags: android, wifi

I want too make many AP scan with a htc phone under Android 1.6. I use the method :

```
wifiManager.startScan();
```

I want to repeat it all the 4 ms. The problem is : Actually, the logcat shows many times : "Failed to initiate AP scan". I searched on this website and I found another method :

```
wifi.startScanActive();
```

But Eclipse doesn't know it. But if this method really exist for Android 1.6, is it a better method for my case than startScan?

So this is the main question : how can I avoid the message "Failed to initiate AP scan" in order to improve my rate of successful scan?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to scan as fast as 4ms on Android.

You would expect 400-500ms minimum depending on different phones.

startScanActive() is a hidden API, you can access it via Reflect

```
Method method = WifiManager.class.getMethod("startScanActive");
method.setAccessible(true);
Object r = method.invoke(null);  // null for static hidden method
```